# How to prevent file overwriting?

Tags: file, arduino, processing

I am working on an Arduino project using processing. There are some sensor values which should be logged, but unfortunately my processing code rewrites the file after each cycle so that I get the last sensor value only. How do I prevent this from happening? I am using the ordinary method by the way. PrintWriter command followed by createWriter.

Comment: If you could add the code that you are using to your question it would help others see what you are doing. The problem you are having will then be much easier for others to help you solve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you want to append to the file (otherwise, it will just overwrite). Something like this:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)))) {  
    out.println("the text");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // couldn't open file
}
```

The `true` at the end of the `PrintWriter` line specifies appending.